# How to add a set of numbers that the user inputted in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I add numbers in between two numbers the user inputted in Python 2.7.  So a person would input 75 and 80 and I want my program to add the numbers in between those two numbers. I am very new to programming and python so any help would be awesome!

Comment: Hint: you should read up on [arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_series).  You don't need to loop, which would be slow if the numbers were very far apart; you can get the answer in one line.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The only way to learn programming is to write your own code, and to get help when you get help with something specific. Your question is getting downvoted because you don't seem to have done any work yourself yet. What are you having trouble with? Reading the numbers? Getting the numbers in between? Adding them up? There are already SO questions about each of these. Good luck.

Comment: I highly recommend following @DSM's advice. Then this becomes a simple math equation rather than requiring any kind of iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example excludes 75 and 80. If you need to include them replace with     print sum(range(n1,n2+1))

```
n1=input('Enter first number ')
n2=input('Enter second number ')
print sum(range(min(n1,n2)+1,max(n1,n2)))
```

Comment: +1 for the use of sum. Only qualm I have about this would be if n1 > n2 it will return 0.

Comment: `print sum(range(min(n1,n2)+1,max(n1,n2)))`

Answer (score 1):

@DSM is right!

```
n1=input('Enter first number ')
n2=input('Enter second number ')
print (n2-n1+1)*(n2+n1)/2
```

Answer (score 0):

to capture user input use `number1 = raw_input('Input number')`. From there I'm not exactly sure what you mean from adding numbers between the two? If you want 76+77+78+79 in that example

```
number1 = raw_input('Input number')
number2 = raw_input('Second number')
result = 0
for n in range(int(number1)+1, int(number2)):
    result+=n
print result
```

Comment: You'd have to cast the numbers as ints, otherwise this breaks. In addition it doesn't cover if number1 > number2.

Comment: You should use `sum` instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sample that should handle a few different situations. Didn't go that in-depth since I don't know the scope of the situation. Realistically you should do some form of type-checking and loop until valid input is entered. However this should get you started:

```
def sumNums(a, b):
    total = 0
    if a < b:
        total = sum(range(a+1, b))
    elif b < a:
        total = sum(range(b+1, a))  
    return total

num1 = int(raw_input("First Number: "))
num2 = int(raw_input("Second Number: "))
print sumNums(num1, num2)
```

However I'm sure there's a more comprehensive way using lists and sum() but it seems like you only need a basic working example.

Answer (score 0):

easy you just go

```
def add(x,y):
    if True:
        return add(x, y)
    else:
        return None


add([1,2,3,4][0], [1,2,3,4][2])
```